# Selenium HtmlUnit Driver Adding extra line

Tags: selenium-webdriver

With the selenium htmlunit driver,I am downloading pagesource.
The downloaded pagesource has extra line(). which is not there in web site page. 
How can I overcome adding extra line in pagesource.

Thanks
Swathi